# Copyright year of Android App out of date

Tags: bug, android-app

[image: Screenshot of Android App about page, with "Copyright 2014 - 2015" highlighted]

Should be 2016, not 2014-2015.

[image: Version 1.0.85; Updated on Apr 13, 2016]

---

- App Version: 1.0.85
- Device Manufacturer: samsung
- Device Model: GT-N8000
- OS Version: 4.1.2 (N8000XXCMJ2)

Comment: Well, since no major development was done for years (only few bug fixes), I'd say it's correct. They have [great](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android-app+status-planned) [plans](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android-app+status-deferred) but not a single one was ever done.

Comment: @shadow Even so,  I doubt it would be that hard to fix. Even bug fixes stilll count as maintaing it,  right?

Comment: Might be... but still, I don't consider it active development.

Comment: @TheKB: Anyway, even if the copyright year is wrong, the copyright still won't expire until many decades from 2015. So it doesn't matter very much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [About section has old copyright date](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/323330/about-section-has-old-copyright-date)