# About section has old copyright date

Tags: bug, android-app

I noticed that the about section has a copyright date range from 2014 to 2015. This should probably be extended to the current year. It makes me wonder why that was apparently hard coded instead of automatically updating to the current year. So maybe this isn't really a bug?

- App Version: 1.0.95

> About
>
> Copyright 2014 – 2015, Stack Exchange Inc.

Comment: Probably an oversight, but I doubt it'll be fixed. The apps aren't really being developed anymore.

Comment: @TheWanderer I agree. I reported it because I noticed it, and it might have some sort of legal meaning that might make it worthwhile to fix even though the app isn't being actively maintained.

Comment: @Erik Given we don't even have an Android developer on our team anymore, it cannot possibly be fixed unless we hire a new one or someone decides they're really bored and learns how to do the necessary adjustments and figures out how to get into our Google Play accounts to push an update. Not to sound pessimistic, but Android app development is as dead as can be right now. It's coming up on 2 years since the last deployed update.

Comment: @animuson fair enough. I suspect the actual fix would be easy to implement. You could probably do a project wide search for "2014 - 2015" and then a simple StackOverflow search to find out how to concatenate the current year to a string. Like you said the hard part would be the ancillary things like getting the project to build locally and figuring out how to publish to Google Play. At the end of the day it doesn't matter how easy something is to fix if it isn't a high enough priority. At least you haven't pulled the app so weirdos like me can still use it. :)

Answer (score 6):

That's not a bug.

The android app isn't actively developed since 2015, so the data is correct.

Comment: The last update was June 30, 2017. So isn't this still a bug since according to your answer the copyright year should extend to 2017?

Comment: @Erik the updates since 2015 were all super minor and trivial, no real change was done. No bug was fixed, and no feature was implemented. So this does not count as "active development". Do note they spent those years on developing a **different app**, known as the "Stack Overflow app".

Comment: the last update mentioned a bug fix related to right to left locales so by your logic it seems like the date should be up to 2017. I didn't know about the other app. I'll have to check it out. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: I didn't see that other app in the Play store. Were you teasing me by talking about the website or is this other app iOS specific?

Comment: @Erik you didn't see it because they removed it without any notice and [without ever replying to questions asking why it was removed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373307/what-happened-to-the-stack-overflow-app-for-android). But it was there, as you can see in this [official blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/05/16/stack-overflow-official-app-launches-ios-android/), and it's still available for iOS in the Apple Store.

Comment: @Shadow *We* didn't remove it. Google did, and nobody could figure out why without going through all the processes to get into those accounts, which nobody really wanted to do because even if we did we probably wouldn't be able to republish it.

Comment: @animuson OK, so why not give such answer? We can't possibly guess that's what happened, and when app vanish into thin air, the most logical reason is that it's being removed by the company who made it.

Comment: There's no real reason to add an end date to a copyright notice. There are some reasons for including not just the original date of copyright, but they're not really useful for software. This is another example of why adding an end date is a poor idea. Since they have indicated the copyright has expired, I'm going to decompile it and submit it to the play store myself. Come at me bro.

Comment: @Won't: That's not an end date, it's a range of start dates.  Part of the work is written in 2014, so its copyright term starts then.  In the year 2014+(age of Mickey Mouse), you'll be able to use any of the copyrightable bits that were released in 2014.  Part is written in 2015, so its copyright term starts a year later and lasts a year longer, until 2015+(age of Mickey Mouse).

Comment: @BenVoigt interesting argument I've not heard before. Do you have a relevant cite you can share?

Comment: @Won't: Here: https://www.copyrightlaws.com/copyright-symbol-notice-year/ which says "The general rule is that the year to include in a copyright notice is the year of first publication of the work [....] New versions or editions of works should contain the publication date of the new version or edition. For constantly evolving websites and blogs that contain works published over several years, the notice may include a range of years (e.g., 2009–2019), starting from the date of the oldest published elements and ending with the date of the newest published elements."

Comment: Thanks, @BenVoigt appreciate it. Been looking for something like that for awhile. Absence of evidence isn't a strong argument for or against something.